# Delete same values from another db table

Tags: database, sqlite

I have two databases with the same structure. How can i delete records from db1.table, that exists in db2.table?

db1 table: a - 1, a - 2, b - 1, c - 1

db2 table: a - 1, a - 2, c - 1, c - 2

result: b - 1

**Update:**

This query doesn't work

```
DELETE t1 
FROM table t1 
JOIN db2.table t2 
WHERE t1.PrdID = t2.PrdID AND t1.CategoryID=t2.CategoryID
```

It gives me error

```
near "t1": syntax error:
```

db2 is attached to db1

Comment: @PeeHaa this method doesn't work for me, see my update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, before delete, test the subquery,

DELETE FROM table1 WHERE (your column) IN (SELECT (your_column) FROM table2)

(Not tested)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564925/slow-delete-in-sqlite