# Slow DELETE in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to update one table from another db. I attach it and do delete and insert. Insert goes fast, but delete took very large time. For 200k of records it took about 1 minute. How to do it faster?

```
db.execSQL("attach database '" + db_path + "' as db2");
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM CategoryProduct_MM WHERE PrdID IN (SELECT PrdID FROM db2.CategoryProduct_MM)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO CategoryProduct_MM SELECT * FROM db2.CategoryProduct_MM");
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

sqlitebrowser do the same operation for 4 secs

**Update:**

here is the structure of my db

```
CREATE TABLE CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID INTEGER, PrdID INTEGER)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_PrdID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID,PrdID);
CREATE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID);
CREATE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_PrdID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(PrdID);
```

Comment: you can use the `drop table` like so : `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CategoryProduct_MM);`

Comment: Do you have index on PrdID  ?

Comment: @NicolasSimon If you drop the table you will delete all rows, while it seems like the user wants to delete only a selection of rows (more specifically those ones whose `PrdId` is present inside another table)

Comment: @NicolasSimon i don't need to delete the table, because it contains another records. i just need to delete records with PrdID that exists in db2

Comment: Have you enabled the [secure-delete setting](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_secure_delete)? Anyway, the first statement that must read all the new records into the cache will appear to be slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with dropping indexes before delete and recreating them after insert.

```
    db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_PrdID_idx");
    db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_idx");
    db.execSQL("DROP INDEX IF EXISTS CategoryProduct_MM_PrdID_idx");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM CategoryProduct_MM WHERE PrdID IN (SELECT PrdID FROM superup.CategoryProduct_MM)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO CategoryProduct_MM SELECT * FROM superup.CategoryProduct_MM");
    db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_PrdID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID,PrdID)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_CatID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(CategoryID)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX CategoryProduct_MM_PrdID_idx ON CategoryProduct_MM(PrdID)");
```

For 200K records it took 7 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem in transactioning deleting operation. Try to delete it.

Instead of deleting you can create new one table and copy there what you need from first table, insert new data, delete first table and rename new table. In this way you need wrap in transaction just table renaming code.